# Unable to disable "immediate file synchronization" of File Watcher in JetBrains product

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, compass-sass, webstorm

I'm using the *compass + sass* File Watcher in my IntelliJ Idea project.

I'm trying to prevent the File Watcher from immediately compiling my code. Here's why:

The immediate compililation triggered by the File Watcher keeps causing errors on my debug page, and breaks the autocomplete in SASS. As I am typing, the file watcher triggers, resulting in compiler errors, which turn each of the autocomplete entries to read "Invalid" instead.

I think disabling the Immediate File Synchronization option of the File Watcher is supposed to be the answer to my problems. The [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d151302e753) reads:

> - If the Immediate file synchronization check box is selected, the File    Watcher is invoked as soon as any changes are made to the source code.
> - If the Immediate file synchronization check box is cleared, the    File Watcher is started upon save (File | Save All, Ctrl+S) or when you move focus from PhpStorm (upon frame deactivation).

So I've tried to clear the check box, to no avail. The File Watcher still runs amok, compiling after what feels like every keystroke.

This is a bug, right? Am I doing something silly?

Comment: That is the correct option. It's possible that you are using some another tool/plugin/software that causes saving of the current document (which triggers File Watcher). Live Edit plugin, for example. There is also an option to trigger file watcher regardless of errors -- it should be disabled. In any case: I hope you have tried restarting IDE -- sometimes helps.

Comment: disable livereload solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately do not have a solid answer, but @LazyOne above appears to be correct as I tried the following steps, and now it appears that the immediate file synchronization is off:

1. Un-check SCSS `Immediate file synchronization` checkbox
2. Disable the LiveEdit plugin
3. Restart Webstorm

Funny thing; even if I re-enable the LiveEdit plugin, it still seems to be working. Perhaps the LiveEdit plugin is caching something with the SCSS plugin and causing issues.

I hope this helps some other poor soul who has spent too much time being annoyed by this issue :-)